# Enviando Email Utilizando JQuery Ajax sem Refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5

Estou tendo problemas tentando utilizar esse método de envio de formulário por email, sem dar refresh na página. Ainda não tenho muitos conhecimentos com Ajax, então não sei bem se o código está correto, até tentei por outros métodos, copiando e colando o código e só mudando algumas coisas pra ver se ia, mas não consegui.
O problema é que ao clicar no botão de enviar, não ocorre nenhuma ação. A função não é chamada.

Código em Js:

```
$(function($) {

        $("#form1").submit(function() {

            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

            $("#status").html("<img src='loader.gif'/>");

            $.post('email.php', {nome: nome, email: email, mensagem: mensagem }, function(envia) {

                    $("#status").slideDown();

                    if (envia != false) {

                        $("#status").html(envia);
                    } 

                    else {

                        $("#status").html("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");

                        $("#nome").val("");
                        $("#email").val("");
                        $("#mensagem").val("");
                    }
            });
        });
       });
```

Formulário:

```
 <form id="form1" class="row" method="post" action="javascript:function()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome:" class="form-control" name="nome"/>
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail:" class="form-control" name="email"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Mensagem:" class="form-control" name="mensagem"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-link" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

require_once("class/class.phpmailer.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SetLanguage("br");
// $mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;   
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$nomeusuario = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
$emailusuario = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);
$mensagem = utf8_decode($_POST['mensagem']);

$mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';

$mail->From = $emailusuario;
$mail->FromName = $nomeusuario;
$mail->AddAddress('', '');
$mail->Subject = "";
$mail->AddBcc($emailusuario);
$mail->Body = $mensagem;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mensagem de erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Mensagem enviada!";
    }

?>
```

Quando tento colocando onsubmit no formulario, aparece uma imagem de erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está o arquivo php?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, e coloquei como está o arquivo php

Comment: ta faltando colocar um botão do tipo submit (ou input submit) no seu formulário

Comment: Editei lá, quando copiei o formulário pra passar pra cá, esqueci desse input

Comment: Está faltando os ids nos inputs, sendo que você ta pegando eles dentro do ajax.

Comment: Orra, verdade, que vacilo besta! kkk mas de qualquer forma, clicando no botão não tem ação nenhuma

Comment: `$mail->ErrorInfo` retorna algo? Tbm coloca `smtpdebug = 1` para ver se esta dando erro.

Comment: Não retorna nada. O certo pra chamar a função é com onsubmit ou com action? Com action não tem ação nenhuma e com onsubmit fica com o erro da imagem, mesmo com smtpdebug = 1 e o errorinfo não retorna nada